# how to change File System (MVFS) to be Case Insensitive but Case Preserving in windows clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

After the installation is it possible to change File System (MVFS) to be Case Insensitive and Case Preserving in windows clearcase 7.1.2.6?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

If you type clearhomebase, you have access to the ClearCase Option.

In the tab "Administration", click on Control Panel, then tab "MVFS".
You will have the possibility to select the "Case Insensitive" and "Case preserving" there.

[image: MVFS options]

---

Note that this operation requires **administrative privileges**, as it involve MVFS (MultiVersion FileSystem, a device which adds a file system on top of the Windows File system, in order to access view contents through the network)

Even if you can change those options, note that Changes to MVFS options do not take effect until you restart your computer.

Comment: I do have that but it complains that "updating registry reqires adminstrative previliges". Since it is installed in my PC, why is it complaining?

Comment: @user2370590 maybe because you don't have administrative privilege?

Comment: my co-worker doesn't need the admin previlege and I do to modify this page. Its a kind of annoying. Do you think it has something to do with atria location broker...I haven't checked but not sure If I should correct my password there.

Comment: @user2370590 no link with the albd. Try to connect as an admin, change that parameter then reboot with a regular account: the setting should be persistent.

Comment: It didn't work tht way. Since it is installed in the pc, the owner of the pc should have the admin priveleges. In this case, probably we might have to uninstall the cleacase and install it with mvfs setting.

Comment: @user2370590 no, if you see the mvfs tab, there is no need to uninstall and reinstall. All you need to do is access those settings with an admin account. The fact that you install an app doesn't give you any special privilege: having admin right has nothing to do with a particular application being installed or not.